# How should I interpret "between Neville and Ron" in the context of this Harry Potter passage?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> They (Hermione and Ron) did not stop arguing all the way down to Snape's dungeon, which gave Harry plenty of time to reflect that **between Neville and Ron** he would be lucky ever to have two minutes of conversation with Cho that he could look back on without wanting to leave the country.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter</sub>

I don't understand "between Neville and Ron" in this context. Can someone help to explain it in the context?

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/194802/how-to-understand-between-neville-and-ron-in-the-context#comment381457_194882

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Compare:

*Between school and my job, I don't have much time for anything else.*

The phrase means "given the combined (encroachments or demands of) school and my job" there is no time left over for other activities.

So, in your example, it would be "given the combined (encroachments or demands of) Neville and Ron" a good two-minute conversation with Cho was unlikely.  The nature of those encroachments or demands is supplied by context.  For example, it could be that the two of them, whether individually or as a duo, were monopolizing Cho's time, or monopolizing Harry's time, or that they were goofing off with each other so that there were constant hijinks and never a quiet moment where Harry could talk with Cho. Whatever.  You'd have to look to the wider context in the book to get a sense of how Ron and Neville were interfering in this.

Answer (score 8):

According to the Oxford Dictionary

**[between](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/between)** [preposition]

> By **combining** the resources or actions of (**two or more people** or other entities)

I didn't remember what's happening exactly at that point of the book but it **may** mean that if you add [**combine**] the time that Harry spends with Neville plus the time that Harry spends with Ron [**two people**] then *he would be lucky ever to have two minutes of conversation with Cho*.

I want to remark that the relevant part in relation with your question is **combine whatever they both are doing. What they are doing exactly is not present in your excerpt.**

Probably in the context of the book the whole sentence is not about Neville and Ron wasting Harry's time but they are **combining their actions somehow to prevent Harry for having a conversation** with Cho.

Comment: Hmmm, that doesn't sound very convincing.

Comment: @Dan As I said, I don't remember exactly what's happening but something that Neville and Ron [between them] are doing prevents Harry for having a conversation with Cho.

Comment: Yes, I recalled each of them managed to prevent him for having a private conversation with Cho one time.

Comment: But I think here it means: being between Neville and Ron, it would be lucky ever to have two minutes of conversation with Cho because they both ruined the chance where he could have a private conversation with cho.

Comment: @dan Yes, it could be, the relevant part is that "between them" means that the "combined efforts of Neville and Ron" are spoiling Harry's chances with Cho. That's what I was trying to express.

Comment: @dan: I think **efforts** is the misleading aspect of an otherwise good explanation.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Well, I updated my post replacing "efforts" by "actions" before your comment. I hope this made it less misleading. :-)

Comment: Yes, as their actions might not rise to the level of intentional efforts.  +1

Answer (score 4):

In the context of the book, if memory serves, Cho came upon Harry while he was sitting with Neville on the Hogwarts Express just after Neville's Mimbulus mimbletonia exploded, covering Harry in stinksap, which he found embarrassing.  Later, Ron angrily challenges Cho on her support of a Quidditch team and picks a fight with her, also embarrassing Harry.

In your quote, Harry is saying that because of Neville and Ron combined, it seems that every time he tries to talk to Cho, he is embarrassed.  It is not necessarily implying that Neville and Ron are working together to embarrass him (or that they are even doing it intentionally) but that their combined actions are making it impossible for him to have a positive conversation with Cho.

Comment: The other answers are technically correct in their definitions of the phrase, but not in their application to the story.  In the context of the story this is the correct answer.

Comment: @Alex It's not often I get to let my Harry Potter geekdom and my love of grammar intersect.

Comment: Check out [dan's profile](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/59517/dan?tab=questions&sort=newest) then. There are several hundred questions, most of which are based on Harry Potter.